# Mechanize::ResponseCodeError (404 => Net::HTTPNotFound unhandled response):

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

Trying to **scrape** images from `https://en.wikipedia.org/` website using mechanize gem. I am getting `Mechanize::ResponseCodeError (404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/FP2A3620_%252823497688248%2529.jpg/119px-FP2A3620_%252823497688248%2529.jpg -- unhandled response):` for this when i try to calculate image size.

Here is my code

```
         def images
          agent = Mechanize.new
          page = agent.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
          page.images.each do |image|
            puts image.url
            size = agent.head( image )["content-length"].to_i/1000
          end  
       end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot access that URL even via browser, are you sure it is valid?

Comment: yes `https://en.wikipedia.org/` this is a valid URL

Comment: I am talking about the one you provided `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/FP2A3620_%252823497688248%2529.jpg/119px-FP2A3620_%252823497688248%2529.jpg`, status code for that page is 404, that's why you cannot parse it. Open with your browser the URL.

Comment: @zhisme Yes but we have to fix those kind of url errors while scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked after that image on wikipedia and it renders just fine. Opened it in a new tab and compared the url from the browser to what mechanize has.

Unescaping the url, did the trick.

```
image_url = CGI.unescape(image.url.to_s)
size = agent.head(image_url)["content-length"].to_i/1000
```

Here is a working [Replit](https://replit.com/@razvan-sv/HideousYummySupport#main.rb).

Comment: Great Thank you.. it works @razvans . I just handled the same with exception to rescue from this error.